# Issue with Resize Method in C++ Multi-dimensional Array Class

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures

I've been working on a C++ class for a multidimensional dynamic array, and I've run into a puzzling issue with the resize method. I've implemented the method to resize the array with new dimensions, but it seems that I'm encountering unexpected behavior.

The issue arises when I try to resize the array using the resize method. I expected the method to preserve the existing data, but it seems that the old data is getting discarded during the resize operation. This is not the behavior I intended.

What is causing this problem in the resize method?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class MultiDimensionalArray {
private:
    vector<vector<T>> array;
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;

public:
    MultiDimensionalArray(size_t rows, size_t cols) : rows(rows), cols(cols) {
        array.resize(rows, vector<T>(cols, T()));
    }

    void resize(size_t newRows, size_t newCols) {
        rows = newRows;
        cols = newCols;
        array.resize(rows, vector<T>(cols, T()));
    }

    T& at(size_t row, size_t col) {
        return array.at(row).at(col);
    }

    void modify(size_t row, size_t col, const T& value) {
        array.at(row).at(col) = value;
    }

    void transpose() {
        vector<vector<T>> transposed(cols, vector<T>(rows, T()));
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                transposed[i][j] = array[i][j];
            }
        }
        array = transposed;
        swap(rows, cols);
    }

    void print() const {
        for (const auto& row : array) {
            for (const auto& elem : row) {
                std::cout << elem << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    MultiDimensionalArray<int> myArray(3, 4);
    myArray.at(0, 0) = 1;
    myArray.at(1, 1) = 2;
    myArray.at(2, 2) = 3;

    myArray.print();
    cout << endl;
    myArray.resize(2, 2);
    myArray.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 0 0 0
0 2 0 0
0 0 3 0

1 0 0 0
0 2 0 0
```

Comment: Which result do you expect? data seem not discarded. Your code only resize row and not columns, but that is unrelated to "discarded data"...

Comment: [OT]: members `rows`/`cols` can be omitted, information already accessible from `std::vector::size()`.

Comment: `array.resize(rows, vector<T>(cols, T()));` does not do what you think it does. It does not `resize` the `array` to have exactly `rows` values, ***and*** every value in the `array` getting resized to `cols` values. It only does the first part, and any ***new*** values in the `array` will, themselves, have `cols` values.

Answer (score 0):

`vector<T>(cols, T())` is a vector default-initialized `T`s, so all zeros in your case.
`array.resize(rows, vector<T>(cols, T()))` turns `array` into `rows` copies of this vector of zeros.

You need to resize in each dimension separately.
For instance,

```
array.resize(rows);
for (auto& row: array) {
    row.resize(cols);
}
```

Comment: Oops, wrote too fast...

Answer (score 0):

> What might be causing this problem in the resize method?

Resizing is a two-step process.

1. Resize the array. This changes the number of rows.
2. Run a loop, and resize each row. This changes the number of columns.

The only change I made to your program was in function `resize`:

```cpp
    void resize(size_t newRows, size_t newCols) {
        rows = newRows;
        cols = newCols;

        // Delete this.
        // array.resize(rows, vector<T>(cols, T()));

        // Add this.
        array.resize(newRows);
        for (auto& row : array)
            row.resize(newCols, T{});
    }
```

Output:

```
1 0 0 0
0 2 0 0
0 0 3 0

1 0
0 2
```

##### Member variables `rows` and `cols` are redundant

@Jarod42 is quite right. You should rewrite your class, and eliminate member variables `rows` and `cols`.

- `rows` is the same as `array.size()`
- `cols` is the same as `array.front().size()`

The formula for `cols` should only be used when `array.size()` is non-zero. Otherwise, `cols` is zero.

Answer (score -1):

I assume the expected behaviour is to resize the grid to have a grid of 2 columns and 2 rows.
So the issue you have is that it is 4 columns and 2 rows.

**What is causing this to happen?**

The `vector::resize` overload you are using takes two parameters:

- The new container size, `n`
- The default value for **added elements**, `val` (*note in your case you are not adding elements*)

To begin with, size of `array` is 4 elements.
Then, you resize it to 2 elements.
*The second parameter*, `val`, *is used **only** when increasing the size of the vector*

Knowing this, it is easy to see that your call to `array.resize` is simply setting the number of rows to 2, and doing nothing to the number of columns.

**How do we fix this?**

You must modify the size of every column as well as every row.

This would do the trick:

```
void resize(size_t newRows, size_t newCols) {
    rows = newRows;
    cols = newCols;
    
    // Set number of rows (you are already doing this). Note that the second argument is redundant as rows will be resized anyway.
    array.resize(rows, vector<T>(cols, T()));
    
    // Iterate each row, and set the number of columns for each.
    for (auto& row : array) {
        row.resize(cols, T());
    }
    
}
```

Comment: @tbxfreeware I've added a comment to reflect this. I've not modified the code though, as applying this change does not help OP to fix their problem.

Comment: @tbxfreeware I agree wholeheartedly, which is why I've added a comment to state this. However I've not modified the code, because doing so would not fix anything from original question. There are several improvements that can be made to the original code, but the answer's job is to fix OP's problem, NOT to refactor OP's code.